How do you search for all results using pagination?
I found that the default setting for search results was far too many for our website so I reduced the maximum results to 250 using the following patch:
<setting name="ContentSearch.SearchMaxResults">
  <patch:attribute name="value">250</patch:attribute>
</setting>

Unfortunately, this has the side effect of limiting the results returned when calling Find-Item.
$careersPath = "/sitecore/content/<company>/<tenant>/<site>/Home/careers/"
$criteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = 'Careers Job Detail' },
    @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = $careersPath }
)
$props = @{
    Index    = "<index-name>"
    Criteria = $criteria
}
                
$careerItems = @(Find-Item @props | Initialize-Item) # Only 250 items


You can make a slight modification to support pagination by looping until each page is returned. You could optimize this further by comparing the page size to the result count to see if you need to make more requests.
$careersPath = "/sitecore/content/<company>/<tenant>/<site>/Home/careers/"
$criteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = 'Careers Job Detail' },
    @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = $careersPath }
)
$props = @{
    Index    = "<index-name>"
    Criteria = $criteria
}
                
$careerItems = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$pageSize = 250
$offset = 0
$keepGoing = $true
while($keepGoing) {
    $pagedItems = @(Find-Item @props -Skip $offset -First $pageSize | Initialize-Item)
    if($pagedItems) {
        $lastCount = $pagedItems.Count
        $offset += $lastCount
        $careerItems.AddRange($pagedItems) > $null
    } else {
        $keepGoing = $false
    }
}

# You can now pass $careerItems to Show-ListView to generate a report.

